# Are "motionless" and "uncovered" fitting words here?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Brad enters the room to find Jerry standing motionless in a corner with his back to the room. Completely uncovered.

(Jerry is trying to hide)

Brad: God, you're bad at this game.

Is "motionless" a fitting word here to tell that he's not moving and not making any sound? Or will "still" be better?

Is "Uncovered" the best word to use here to tell that he's not hiding behind anything and therefore is very much exposed to being seen?

Comment: This is really an editing question. Anyway, completely visible is better.

Answer (score 1):

"Completely uncovered" is not a good choice here, as in many dialects it will imply 'naked'. "In plain view" would work.
Motionless is fine, altho it doesn't really fit with the other characters reaction.